# How do I find the current page lock promotion value in sybase?

Tags: sybase

I've done this before but I lost my notes. There's lots of web pages from sybase infocenter explaining how to SET it, but I need to find the current value on two machines so I can compare them.

Answer (score 2):

```
sp_helpconfig "row lock promotion"
```

At server level.
 
or

```
sp_help table_name
```

Should do the job on table level. 
See this [link](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/asg1192e/asefun92/@Generic__BookTextView/23355;hf=0?DwebQuery=lock+hashtable+size) as a example.